# How to test missing extra requirements?

Tags: python, testing, plone, buildout

On a [python distribution](https://github.com/collective/collective.contentalerts) (Plone related) that I'm developing I added an extra requirement: `async`

Thus, if someone wants to use it without async features that's fine, but they have also that possibility. Code has already been updated to use it conditionally.

But now the question is: on my test runner I declare my own distribution to install the `async` extra so I can test the async functionality, but that prevents me from testing the non-async code paths.

How can one handle this?

Answer (score 3):

I see two possibilities:

- build two test runners with different dependencies installed.
- if this is not acceptable, you could condition the imports of your optional dependency not only on the availability of the package but also on the value of a global variable. Your test runner could run tests twice with the variable configured on and off.

Comment: for some ideas, check, for instance, the work I'm doing here https://github.com/collective/collective.cover/pull/482